# How do I call spiders from different projects with different pipelines from a python script?

Tags: python, api, windows-7, scrapy, scrapyd

I have a three different spiders in different scrapy projects called REsale, REbuy and RErent, each with their own pipeline that directs their output to various MySQL tables on my server.  They all run OK when called using `scrapy crawl`.  Ultimately, I want a script that can run as a service on my windows 7 machine that runs the spiders at different intervals.  ATM, I am stuck at the scrapy API.  I cant even get it to run one of the spiders!  Is there somewhere special this needs to be saved?  At the moment it's just in my root python directory. Sale, Buy and Rent are the names of the spiders I would call using `scrapy crawl` and sale_spider etc. is the spider's .py file.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy import log
from REsale.spiders.sale_spider import Sale
from REbuy.spiders.buy_spider import Buy
from RErent.spiders.sale_spider import Rent

spider = Buy()
crawler = Crawler(Settings())
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()

spider = Rent()
crawler = Crawler(Settings())
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()

spider = Sale()
crawler = Crawler(Settings())
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()
```

This is returning the error:

```
c:\Python27>File "real_project.py", line 5, in <module>
from REsale.spiders.sale_spider import Sale
ImportError: No module named REsale.spiders.sale_spider
```

I am new so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you'll look at http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/, a ready made scrapy daemon for deploying and scheduling scrapy spiders

Comment: This looks perfect for what I want but not straight forward to implement on win 7.  Can you point me to how to install scrapyd for win 7?

Comment: or even just what paths need to be set up?

Comment: didn't see Windows for quite a while, sorry, but I see in the docs it says config file should be at c:\scrapyd\scrapyd.conf (Windows), check out http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/scrapyd.html#scrapyd-configuration-file

Comment: I have run `setup.py install` from within the unzipped scrapyd folder, located in my python27 directory.  It seems to install but then typing `scrapyd` in the cmd line gives me: not recognized as an internal or external command. Using the python shell I get: `scrapyd is not defined` and using the scrapy shell I get: `nameerror: scrapyd is not defined`.  Does this mean I have not installed scrapyd package correctly?

Comment: I have asked another question about installing scrapyd in win7 because I think I have probably not installed it properly.  I cant seem to find any information on how to do this. Any tips greatly appreciated...

Comment: my best offer for you, and this is arguably the best recommendation you'll get in your entire career is to give this a try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: Thanks @Guy,  my solution in hindsight would have been to just use something like task scheduler to run scrapy crawl commands.  Anyway, now I can enjoy the view from ubuntu, despite having had no sleep for the last three days whilst on a ubuntu scrapyd binge!